# Safari prompt to save credit card blocks submit

Tags: javascript, browser, safari

Building a checkout form. When I have the credit card details and I submit them on Safari there's the usual prompt to save credit card details for later. The annoying thing is that this prompt sort of gets in the way of my conversion and basically does not allow the POST to complete and the new page (error/complete) to load.

I was wondering if there is a less intrusive way to allow customers to save cc details or, in the other hand, prevent safari from loading that prompt.

Any ideas or it is just as it is?

Comment: I have a feeling that this is a problem that should rather be fixed on the side of your workflow then by breaking Safari's UX patterns. What problems is is causing exactly?

Answer (score 0):

You can [disable autocomplete completely](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Securing_your_site/Turning_off_form_autocompletion) for your credit card field, which should also disable the save feature:

```
<input autocomplete="off" />
```